# How to do i18n and create Windows Installer of Haskell programs?

Tags: haskell, internationalization, software-distribution

I'm considering using Haskell to develop for a little commercial project. The program must be internationalized (to Simplified Chinese, to be specific), and my customer requests that it should be delivered in a one-click Windows Installer form. So basically these are the two problems I'm facing now:

1. I18n of Haskell programs: the method described in [Internationalization of Haskell programs](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Internationalization_of_Haskell_programs) did work (partially) if I change the command of executing the program from `LOCALE=zh_CN.UTF-8 ./Main` to `LANG=zh_CN.UTF-8 ./Main` (I'm working on Ubuntu 10.10), however, the Chinese output is garbled, and I've no idea why is that.
2. Distribution on Windows: I'm used to work under Linux and build & package my Haskell programs using Cabal, but what is the most natural way to create a one-click Windows Installer from a cabalized Haskell package? Is the package [bamse](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/bamse) the right way to go?

------  Details for the first problem ------

What I did was:

```
$ hgettext -k __ -o messages.pot Main.hs
$ msginit --input=messages.pot --locale=zh_CN.UTF-8
  (Edit the zh_CN.po file, adding Chinese translation)
$ mkdir -p zh_CN/LC_MESSAGES
$ msgfmt --output-file=zh_CN/LC_MESSAGES/hello.mo zh_CN.po
$ ghc --make Main.hs
$ LANG=zh_CN.UTF-8 ./Main
```

And the output was like:

[image: terminal output]

This indicates gettext is actually working, but for some reason the generated zh_CN.mo file is broken (my guess). I'm pretty sure my zh_CN.po file is encoded in UTF-8. Plus, aside from using  `System.IO.putStrLn`, I also tried `System.IO.UTF8.putStrLn` to output the string, which didn't work either.

Comment: Hey nice. I did not even know that bamse existed...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For the first question, the solution is to add `decodeString` from `Codec.Binary.UTF8.String` to the gettext function `__`, like this:

```
__ :: String -> String
__ = decodeString . unsafePerformIO . getText
```

And then everything works just fine.

Answer (score 0):

for the first question, is it possible that you didn't install correct font or the font is not set to be used in the terminal.

Comment: I don't think so... My terminal has no problem displaying normal Chinese characters encoded in UTF-8. Please see my revision.